My code for conditional sum in vba is showing error
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet                        'for looping worksheets
Dim i As Double    
Dim lastrowG As Long
Dim lastrow As Double

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowG = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 2 To lastrow                                                                        
                   ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow), ws.Cells(i, 9), ws.Range("G1:G" & lastrowG))
            Next i
Next ws

End Sub

I want to compare column A data with column I. If the data is equal, then I want to add the data of column G and show it in column L.I am not getting any error but it finally ends in excel not responding. The data in column A and I are strings. it's a 94000 rows data. Does anybody know what could be the reason?

Writing cell-by-cell for 94000 cells is quite slow.

Tries 1. With shorter range. 2. Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Where are you comparing the data in columns A and I? Why not write a formula to do this? Sample data and expected outcome may be useful here

If you're dead set on using VBA to do this, then write your data to an array and do your processing within the array and write the results back to Excel (at its best this is still a bad option).  The best solution is to use a structured table (List Object) and then your formula is easy.  If you're pasting in your data from an external source, there's is a VB script somewhere on SO that speeds that process up massively, but I can't find it and my copies have been tweaked pretty heavily.

"Excel not responding" means probably that Excel is still busy with calculation. Having > 90k rows in Col A and Col I means at the end of the day that more than 8 billion comparisons needs to be done (every value in Col A with every value in Col I). That takes time...
I have quickly created a different attempt:

In a first step, read all values from col A, col I and col G into memory.

Now build a dictionary of all values of col G and sum up all values of col G.

Third step is to loop over all values in col A and check if the dictionary has an entry for that value.

Last step is to write the results back to the sheet (into col L)


Relevant piece of the code:
With ws
    ' Read Data into arrays
    Dim Col1Data, Col2Data, NumData, ResultData
    Dim col1RowCount As Long, col2RowCount As Long
    col1RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Col1Data = .Range("A2:A" & col1RowCount)
    col2RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row
    Col2Data = .Range("I2:I" & col2RowCount)
    NumData = .Range("G2:G" & col2RowCount)

    Dim sumDict As Dictionary
    Set sumDict = New Dictionary
    
    ' Loop over the data in Col2 (=I) and calculate the sum for every value
    Dim row As Long
    Dim key As String, value As Double
    For row = 1 To UBound(Col2Data)
        key = Col2Data(row, 1)
        value = NumData(row, 1)
        sumDict(key) = sumDict(key) + value
    Next
    
    ' Get the sum of every value Col1 (=A)
    ReDim ResultData(1 To UBound(Col1Data), 1 To 1)
    For row = 1 To UBound(Col1Data)
        key = Col1Data(row, 1)
        If sumDict.Exists(key) Then ResultData(row, 1) = sumDict(key)
    Next
    
    ' Write back result to dest column (=L)
    .Range("L2").Resize(UBound(Col1Data), 1) = ResultData
End With

Add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (or use Late Binding) to make the code work (drawback: Scripting Runtime and therefore Dictionaries doesn't exist on a Mac).
I created a test sheet with 100.000 rows, both for col A and G. Runtime was maybe 1/2 second.
N.B.: In your code, change data type for i and lastrow to Long

A VBA SumIf: Sum Per Category

The Calling Procedure
Sub RetrieveSumsPerCategory()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        SumPerCategory ws
    Next ws
            
    MsgBox "Sums per category retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub

Main
' Performs a 'SumIf' on a single worksheet.
Sub SumPerCategory(ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN As String = "A" ' 2. ... here...
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "G" ' 3. ... and return this...
    Const DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN As String = "I" ' 1. Look for this...
    Const DST_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "L" ' 4. ... here.
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2

    ' Reference the source ranges.
    Dim slrg As Range, srrg As Range, sRowsCount As Long
    With ws.Cells(FIRST_ROW, SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN)
        sRowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If sRowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no source lookup data
        Set slrg = .Resize(sRowsCount)
        Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_RETURN_COLUMN)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination ranges.
    Dim dlrg As Range, drrg As Range, dRowsCount As Long
    With ws.Cells(FIRST_ROW, DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN)
        dRowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If dRowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no destination lookup data
        Set dlrg = .Resize(dRowsCount)
        Set drrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_RETURN_COLUMN)
    End With
    
    ' Clear existing data in the destination return column.
    drrg.ClearContents ' keep formatting, or not 'drrg.Clear'
    
    ' Return the source lookup and return values in arrays.
    Dim lData() As Variant: lData = GetRange(slrg)
    Dim rData() As Variant: rData = GetRange(srrg)
    
    ' Define a dictionary whose keys will hold the unique lookup values
    ' as strings and whose items will hold the corresponding sums for each key.
    Dim sdict As Object: Set sdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sdict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' A=a
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the source arrays and populate the dictionary.
    Dim r As Long, Value As Variant, lString As String, rNumber As Double
    For r = 1 To sRowsCount
        Value = lData(r, 1)
        If IsNoErrorNoBlank(Value) Then
            lString = CStr(Value)
            Value = rData(r, 1)
            rNumber = 0
            If IsNoErrorNoBlank(Value) Then
                If IsNumeric(Value) Then rNumber = CDbl(Value)
            End If
            sdict(lString) = sdict(lString) + rNumber
        End If
    Next r
    If sdict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no matches
    
    ' Return the destination lookup values in an array and define
    ' the destination return array.
    lData = GetRange(dlrg)
    ReDim rData(1 To dRowsCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the destination arrays
    ' and lookup each value of the lookup array in the dictionary keys.
    ' If found, return the value of the corresponding item, the sum,
    ' in the same row of the destination array.
    For r = 1 To dRowsCount
        Value = lData(r, 1)
        If IsNoErrorNoBlank(Value) Then
            lString = CStr(Value)
            If sdict.Exists(lString) Then rData(r, 1) = sdict(lString)
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write the values of the destination return array
    ' to the destination return range.
    drrg.Value = rData

End Sub

Help
' Returns the values of a (single-area) range in a 2D one-based array.
Function GetRange(ByVal rg As Range) As Variant
    With rg.Areas(1)
        If .Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = .Value
            GetRange = Data
        Else
            GetRange = .Value
        End If
    End With
End Function

' Returns a boolean indicating whether a value is not an error or a blank.
Function IsNoErrorNoBlank(ByVal Value As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsError(Value) Then Exit Function
    If Len(Value) = 0 Then Exit Function
    IsNoErrorNoBlank = True
End Function

